# Google Maps 3 : when any marker clicked same infoWindow opens up

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have several markers on my google map. Each has text that should show when it is clicked in the form of an infowindow. The code for all this is below. Hwever, the problem is that, when I click any marker on the map, its always the same marker that the map zooms in on and the same marker's infoWindow pops up. No matter where I click its always the same.

Wondering if there is something in plain sight that Im doing wrong. Could someone give me some advice?

```
  function getlistings()  
   {  
     $.getJSON('list/listings.json', processlistings);  
   }  



function processlistings(data)   
{  
    listings = data;  
    markersArray = [];  
    for( i = 0; i < listings.length; i++)   
    {  
        var listing = listings[i];  
        var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(listing["latitude"]), parseFloat(listing["longitude"]));  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position : markerLatLng,  
            title: listing['name'],  
            map : map  
        });  

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(  
        {  
          content: listing['name'],  
          position: markerLatLng  
        });  

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()   
    {  
        infowindow.open(map);  

    });  

    markersArray.push(marker);  
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you loop through your data, you are creating an `InfoWindow` many times over. At the end of the loop, you have one `InfoWindow` at `markerLatLng`.

When the marker is clicked, `infowindow.open()` is called, which uses the infowindow at `markerLatLng`.

You need to use a function closure, as demonstrated at http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html

```
//loop through markers, but create each with a helper function
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.82589,-79.10040);
          var marker = createMarker(point,'Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window')

    function createMarker(latlng, html) {
        var contentString = html;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Good point, but add "return marker; " at the end of the createMarker function.

Comment: The key is to use a separate function to create the marker, then push it in the map.

Answer (score 0):

as you loop through the listings, you're overwriting the infowindow var contents. instead you need to change the click to set the contents to `this.title`

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Loading...'});;    
function processlistings(data)   
    {  
        listings = data;  
        markersArray = [];  
        for( i = 0; i < listings.length; i++)   
        {  
            var listing = listings[i];  
            var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(listing["latitude"]), parseFloat(listing["longitude"]));  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                position : markerLatLng,  
                title: listing['name'],  
                map : map  
            });  

        markersArray.push(marker);  
        } 
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            var marker = markersArray[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(this.title);
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
```