# Only 1 contentString displays in custom Google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have used this tutorial

[adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website](http://stiern.com/tutorials/adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website/)

to create a custom google map using V3 of the Google Maps API, **But have hit a problem** :

When the markers are clicked, the info box pops up, but each different marker on the map displays the same *contentString*.

You can see it here: http://tcchurch.com.au/table1/index.php/missions

I assume there is a problem with my code that is preventing the individual *contentStrings* from displaying. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps 3 : when any marker clicked same infoWindow opens up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247559/google-maps-3-when-any-marker-clicked-same-infowindow-opens-up)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content for each infowindow  [**Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(html);//relevant html
      infowindow.open(map,companyMarker);    
    });
```